# How to get the body text of email with imaplib?

Tags: python-3.x, imaplib

I am in python3.4 .

```
import imaplib
import email
user="XXXX"
password="YYYY"
con=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
con.login(user,password)
con.list()

con.select("INBOX")
result,data=con.fetch(b'1', '(RFC822)')
raw=email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])

>>> raw["From"]
'xxxx'
>>> raw["To"]
'python-list@python.org'
>>> raw["Subject"]
'Re:get the min date from a list'
```

When i run 'print(raw)' there are many lines of the body of the email ,
i can't get it with  `raw[TEXT]`  OR `raw['TEXT']` OR `raw['BODY']` ,
how can i  get the body of the email text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking it for a header named `TEXT` or `BODY`, and obviously there is no such thing. I think you're mixing up IMAP4 part names (the things you pass in `con.fetch`) and RFC2822 header names (the things you use in an `email.message.Message`).

As the [`email.message`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html) documentation explains, a `Message` consists of headers and a payload. The payload is either a string (for non-multipart messages) or a list of sub-`Message`s (for multipart). Either way, what you want here is `raw.get_payload()`.

If you want to handle both, you can either first check `raw.is_multipart()`, or you can check the type returned from `get_payload()`. Of course you have to do decide what you want to do in the case of a multipart message; what counts as "the body" when there are three parts? Do you want the first? The first `text/plain`? The first `text/*`? The first `text/plain` if there is one, the first `text/*` if not, and the first of anything if even that doesn't exist? Or all of them concatenated together?

Let's assume you just want the first one. To do that:

```
def get_text(msg):
    if msg.is_multipart():
        return get_text(msg.get_payload(0))
    else:
        return msg.get_payload(None, True)
```

If you want something different, hopefully you can figure out how to do it yourself. (See the `get_content_type` and/or `get_content_maintype` methods on `Message`.)

Comment: In my console python3.4 : raw.is_multipart  True ,but raw.get_payload(None,True) get the result.

Comment: How about using get_body method? - see link for reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html

Answer (score 0):

Following up using Python 3.8 - parses all the parts that have an associated encoding and turns it into a single HTML page

```py
import imaplib
import email
import webbrowser
import tempfile
import webbrowser


def email_to_html(parsed):
    all_parts = []
    for part in parsed.walk():
        if type(part.get_payload()) == list:
            for subpart in part.get_payload():
                all_parts += email_to_html(subpart)
        else:
            if encoding := part.get_content_charset():
                all_parts.append(part.get_payload(decode=True).decode(encoding))
    return ''.join(all_parts)


# Login
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")  
result = imap.login("username", "password")

# Select the inbox, grab only the unseen emails
status, resp = imap.select('INBOX')
status, response = imap.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
unread_msg_nums = response[0].split()

email_bodies = []
for idx in unread_msg_nums:
    _, msg = imap.fetch(str(int(idx)), "(RFC822)")
    for response in msg:
        if isinstance(response, tuple):
            raw_email = response[1]
            parsed = email.message_from_bytes(raw_email)
            email_bodies.append(email_to_html(parsed))



# If you want to view/check the emails in your browser
def display(html):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False, suffix='.html') as f:
        url = 'file://' + f.name
        f.write(html)
        webbrowser.open(url)


for body in email_bodies:
    display(body)
```